# Specify in Rust that a generic type supports coercion to a primitive type

Tags: generics, rust, enums, coercion

In Rust, I have several different enums that are all `#[repr(u32)]`, meaning I can use `as` to cast them to a `u32`:

```rust
#[repr(u32)]
enum Foo {A, B, C}

fn f(foo: Foo) {
    dbg!(foo as u32);
}
```

Now I want to write a generic function that can take any of those enums:

```rust
fn f<T>(t: T) {
    dbg!(t as u32);
}
```

But I can't, because Rust doesn't know that `T` supports that coercion:

> an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object

I tried marking `T` as `Into<u32>`, but it's not, and I can't even easily implement it because the enums are coming from another crate. The best I can come up with is defining and implementing a new trait just for this, along the lines of:

```rust
#[repr(u32)]
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
enum Foo {A, B, C}

trait Argh: Copy {
    fn to_u32(&self) -> u32;
}

impl Argh for Foo {
    fn to_u32(&self) -> u32 {
        *self as u32
    }
}

fn f<T: Argh>(t: T) {
    dbg!(t.to_u32());
}
```

But this makes me very sad. Is there some type specifier I can put on `T` to tell Rust that `T as u32` is valid?

Comment: Your own trait is the way to go, though I'd name it and the function `AsU32::as_u32`. The docs you cite already have all casts in them **between** primitive types and to trait objects, neither of which apply.